# How to change Max Payne 3 game run configuration?

Tags: max-payne-3

Is there any in-game or before start configuration menu?

I only found commandline arguments - [link](http://support.rockstargames.com/entries/21498272-full-list-of-command-line-parameters-for-max-payne-3-on-pc), but I cant believe there is no GUI to it.

Comment: Command line arguments are exactly that.  They hail back from DOS days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no before game GUI to set config, but after intro there is a menu and then you can navigate to GUI with options to set all stuff - controls, audio, video.

BTW: commandline arguments in 'commandline.txt' does not seem to work at all.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question, which is weird since you asked it...  Is the answer no, there's not a configuration screen accessible before the main menu?